# Is there some theorem that proves that entanglement is necessary for quantum advantage?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-advantage

Gottesman-Knill theorem kind of implies that entanglement is not sufficient to produce quantum advantage because it can be simulated in many cases (for Clifford gates combinations). Also it is kind of clear that a single qubit is not going to cut it, so some two or more qubit gates are needed. Is there a similar theorem to show that entanglement is at least necessary for quantum advantage?

Comment: Here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17717/9474

Comment: @TristanNemoz more like the former comment

Comment: @Egretta.Thula does that leave the possibility of having an advantage with mixed state without much entanglement?

Comment: @Mauricio, the paper mentioned in that answer discussed this point also. I updated the answer to include the related excerpt from the paper.

Comment: @Egretta.Thula this is mostly what I was looking for. Could you explain it in more layman terms?